# C# Raycasting / Find closest rectangle from direction

Tags: c#, rectangles, raycasting

So, I'm trying to find a way to find the first **Rectangle** (From a list of rectangles, all 2D) that my **Point** will hit, going in a specific direction (In C#), however I cannot seem to correctly describe the terminology (If there is such a thing for this, the closest thing I found is raycasting).

My goal is to start from a specific "Point" (In this case the asteterik- * seen from the example below), and from there choose a specific direction (Left, Right, Down, Up) (No Angles). So let's say we choose Down, then the first rect that it would hit is "I'M A RECT 2", and therefore should return this.

I know all the positions and sizes of the Rectangles already so I got that information.

How do I go about doing this?

```
     *       [I'M A RECT 1]


[I'M A RECT 2]  
               [I'M A RECT 3]
[I'M A RECT 4]
```

Comment: You can just simulate the ray-casting, easier in your case even since there is only 4 directions. And find the first rectangle hit by the closest point in the one of the 4 rays(sequence of points originating from your **Point**).

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Interesting, would it be possibly for you to give me some example code? :)

Comment: Is your coordinates in int, or float/double?

Comment: Floats. They are Rectangles/Bounding Boxes that contain a Left, Top, Width and Height. @Xiaoy312

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I added a comment to your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the rectangle can intersect with the ray originating from the point, and then compute the distance from the `point`:

```
var point = new PointF(1.2f, 2.5f);
var rectangles = new RectangleF[]
{
    new RectangleF(1, 1, 1, 1),
    new RectangleF(3, 1, 1, 1),
    new RectangleF(5, 2, 1, 1),
};

var hit = rectangles
    .Select(x =>
    {
        if (IsBetween(point.X, x.Left, x.Left + x.Width))
            return new { Rectangle = x, Distance = GetClosestDistance(point.Y, x.Top - x.Height, x.Top) as float? };
        else if (IsBetween(point.X, x.Top - x.Height, x.Top))
            return new { Rectangle = x, Distance = GetClosestDistance(point.Y, x.Left, x.Left + x.Width) as float? };
        else return new { Rectangle = x, Distance = default(float?) };
    })
    .Where(x => x.Distance != null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Distance)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.Rectangle;

bool IsBetween(float value, float lBound, float uBound) => lBound <= value && value <= uBound;
float GetClosestDistance(float value, float p0, float p1) => Math.Min(Math.Abs(p0 - value), Math.Abs(p1 - value));
```

---

Edit:

```
var hit = RayTest(point, rectangles, RayDirections.Right | RayDirections.Down) // or, try just `Down`
    .Where(x => x.Success)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Distance)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.Target;

[Flags]
public enum RayDirections { None = 0, Left = 1 << 0, Up = 1 << 1, Right = 1 << 2, Down = 1 << 3, All = (1 << 4) - 1 }
public class RayHit<T>
{
    public T Target { get; }
    public float? Distance { get; }
    public bool Success => Distance.HasValue;

    public RayHit(T target, float? distance)
    {
        this.Target = target;
        this.Distance = distance;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<RayHit<RectangleF>> RayTest(PointF point, IEnumerable<RectangleF> rectangles, RayDirections directions = RayDirections.All)
{
    if (directions == RayDirections.None)
        return Enumerable.Empty<RayHit<RectangleF>>();

    var ray = new
    {
        Horizontal = new
        {
            LBound = directions.HasFlag(RayDirections.Left) ? float.MinValue : point.X,
            UBound = directions.HasFlag(RayDirections.Right) ? float.MaxValue : point.X,
        },
        Vertical = new
        {
            LBound = directions.HasFlag(RayDirections.Down) ? float.MinValue : point.Y,
            UBound = directions.HasFlag(RayDirections.Up) ? float.MaxValue : point.Y,
        },
    };

    return rectangles
        .Select(x =>
        {
            float left = x.Left, right = x.Left + x.Width;
            float top = x.Top, bottom = x.Top - x.Height;

            if (IsBetween(point.X, left, right) && (IsBetween(top, ray.Vertical.LBound, ray.Vertical.UBound) || IsBetween(bottom, ray.Vertical.LBound, ray.Vertical.UBound)))
                return new RayHit<RectangleF>(x, GetClosestDistance(point.Y, bottom, top) as float?);
            else if (IsBetween(point.X, bottom, top) && (IsBetween(left, ray.Horizontal.LBound, ray.Horizontal.UBound) || IsBetween(right, ray.Horizontal.LBound, ray.Horizontal.UBound)))
                return new RayHit<RectangleF>(x, GetClosestDistance(point.Y, left, right) as float?);
            else return new RayHit<RectangleF>(x, default);
        });

    bool IsBetween(float value, float lBound, float uBound) => lBound <= value && value <= uBound;
    float GetClosestDistance(float value, float p0, float p1) => Math.Min(Math.Abs(p0 - value), Math.Abs(p1 - value));
}
```

note: In both version, there is a bug when the point is inside the rectangle. The distance computed will be the distance to the closest edge, instead of 0 or negative value.

Comment: Hmm, how would you specify a single direction tho? Your code makes sense, but If I only wanna get the "hit" based on a specific direction (For example from Point and down DOWNWARDS (Or other directions) (No angels, just straight vertical)).